# How do you store double quotes in Postgres array of composite type?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

How do you pass double quotes to an array of composite type?

When I escape the double quote with a slash \" it appears that postgres strips it out.

My server has standard_conforming_strings set ON.

Using this composite type:

```
CREATE TYPE public.type_strings AS (
    string_one VARCHAR(500),
    string_two VARCHAR(1000)
);
```

And running this block of code:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    v_strings public.type_strings[] := '{"(One,string with \"quotes\")","(Two,string with \\\\slash\\\\ + ''apos'' + \\,comma\\, + (parens\\))"}';

BEGIN

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS _results;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE _results AS
    SELECT 
        string_one,
        string_two
    FROM UNNEST(v_strings) x(
        string_one,
        string_two);

END $$;

SELECT * FROM _results;
```

Produces these results:

```
string_one      string_two
----------      -------------------------------------------------
One             string with quotes
Two             string with \slash\ + 'apos' + ,comma, + (parens)
```

Notice the double quotes are missing in the first row.  I want to know how to escape the double quote so it is preserved, like this:

```
string_one      string_two
----------      -------------------------------------------------
One             string with "quotes"
Two             string with \slash\ + 'apos' + ,comma, + (parens)
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use three escaped double quotes:

```
select *
from unnest('{"(One,string with \"\"\"quotes\"\"\")","(Two,unimportant)"}'::type_strings[]);

 string_one |      string_two      
------------+----------------------
 One        | string with "quotes"
 Two        | unimportant
(2 rows)
```

There is also more pleasant syntax:

```
select *
from unnest (array[('One', 'string with "quotes"'), ('Two', 'unimportant')]::type_strings[]);
```

Nevertheless, using arrays of composite type in Postgres is a way through torment, a waste of time and energy. There are more natural, more effective and much simpler alternatives in the databases world. I encourage you to try to find them.

Comment: "*using arrays of composite type in Postgres is [...] a waste of time and energy*" - I couldn't agree more!

Comment: @klin Our services are using arrays of composite type to pass in rows of data.  I am more inclined to use JSON.  What would you suggest as the best format?

Comment: In most cases a complex structure can be implemented in a database as several related tables. This is a model solution in which json can serve as the medium of data exchange. Storing data in json format may be a simplified solution, usually less efficient but simpler to design.

Comment: @klin Thanks for your comments, they are very much appreciated. The data is stored in normalized tables as the appropriate data type (ints, varchar, etc).  We only use an array of composite type as function parameters.  However it seems that passing strings would be easier in JSON.

Comment: Json in Postgres needs some practice but is really comfortable. The only drawback is the need to cast to original types but it's basically a trifle.